# -bash: mvn: command not found . in mac

Tags: macos, maven, maven-3

I have set correct path of JAVA and maven in mac still i am getting error when i try to see maven version:   -bash: mvn: command not found

I have set path in bash file as below:
export JAVA_HOME=/Library⁩/Java⁩/JavaVirtualMachines⁩/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk⁩/Contents⁩/Home
export MAVEN_HOME=/Users⁩/aadityaverma⁩/Downloads⁩/apache-maven-3.6.0⁩
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin

Note:
java -version - it is working fine, but 
mvn --version Getting error as mentioned above,
mvn -version Getting error as mentioned above

Comment: Please provide a MCVE.

Comment: In which file have you added the `export PATH`?

Comment: I have added it in .bash_profile file.

Answer (score 0):

Modify .bash_profile as follow:

```
$ vim .bash_profile 

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

$ source .bash_profile
```

Then restart CLI and run maven again

`mvn -version`

More information about [Important Java directories on Mac OS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1170/_index.html)